# What method can I use in python to determine the likelihood of a value based on past data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction

I have a large "time series" dataset that looks something like this:

```
Date    Day of the week   Days Since last Happy    Out of town     Happy
1/1/20  Monday            0                        1               1
1/2/20  Tuesday           1                        0               0
1/3/20  Wednesday         2                        0               0
1/4/20  Thursday          0                        0               1
```

I want to predict the "Happy" observation for future days, based on the previous observations. I know intuitively that there is a correlation between these input variables (like day of the week, days since last happy observation, etc), but I want to know how strong those input variables correlate to the "happy" observation.

What modeling technique should I use? Poissidon? Markov Chain? Linear regression?

Comment: I second @Roim, the "best" model is going to be intimately tied to what the data looks like. How strong are the variables correlated? Which variables are strongest? Machine learning is always weighing two options, too many variables and I overfit, too few variables and I don't have enough predictive power, and that is after you have a model you think will work.

Answer (score 0):

The question you are asking, "how to predict" it's the major question of the entire machine learning field, so we can not answer that for you.
If you want some simple models to start, you can use models in sklearn package such as Decision Tree or KNN.

If you are looking to understand correlation between variables, you can use `DataFrame.corr(method='pearson')` to get correlation matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Bidirectional variational autoencoders, like the one used in GPT-2